# WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets fails with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to run simple Android Wear app on S5 with KitKat. The app is just sample generated by Android Studio. When I run the app it fails with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets
```

I've found the class and there's no `requestApplyInsets` method indeed.

I'm using the latest version of the support library for wearable which is 1.0.0.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77'
}
```

Is it possible to run it on API 19?

Comment: You're trying to run an Android Wear app on a S5 with KitKat? Or on an Android Wear watch attached to the S5 with KitKat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's my fault. Looks like if you have `wear` module in your application it is built and installed by  default (instead of `app` module).

To build and install Android app from terminal now I have to run

```
gradlew app:iD
```

Where `app` is my plain Android project (named `mobile` by default). Running it without `app:` prefix installs `wear` app.