# Android wear app not supported to 4.4.2

Tags: android, wear-os

I am new to android wear developement.Is Android wear applications supported to kitkat 4.4.2. I am using ndroid.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub for supporting rect and round shapes but i am getting exception when i am running in android 4.4.2. There is any support libraries for supporting android 4.4.2 wear devices.if you have any idea about this issue please suggest me.

I am getting below exception

ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets.

Comment: [Maybe this question can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295800/watchviewstub-requestapplyinsets-fails-with-nosuchmethoderror)?

Answer (score 0):

The first android wear watches came with API20 which is 4.4W.2 (Kitkat Wear)
You can have the wear app and phone app set to different minSdk's.